# Convert a SQL query to elastic JSON query

Tags: sql, json

I want to convert the following SQL statement into a elastic json query

```
SELECT distinct(STATUS), count(STATUS), TO_DATE (dtcreated, 'DD.MON.YYYY') 
FROM transaction
GROUP BY
    TO_DATE (dtcreated, 'DD.MON.YYYY'), status 
ORDER BY TO_DATE (dtcreated, 'DD.MON.YYYY')
```